# Accessors: setter does not work

Tags: javascript

I am playing with Javascript accessor properties (I am restarting from zero to study javascript), trying to create getter and setter for a simple object, here the code:

```
var dummy = {
        name: 'empty',
        description: 'static description',

        get nameAccessor(){return 'name value is: ' + this.name;},
        set nameAccessor(value){ this.name = value;},

        get descAccessor(){return 'desccription value is: ' + this.description;},
};

console.log(dummy.nameAccessor);
console.log(dummy.nameAccessor('Mazinga'));
console.log(dummy.nameAccessor);
```

But it throws an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property 'nameAccessor' of object # is not
>   a function

when it executes the setter code:

```
    console.log(dummy.nameAccessor('Mazinga'));
```

What's going wrong here?

**EDIT**:

Ok, it seems to be not a well-known feature of javascript, butI followed this example from 
[Javascript: Definitive Guide](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596805527)

```
var o = { 
          data_prop: value,
          get accessor_prop() { /* function body here */ },
          set accessor_prop(value) { /* function body here */ }
    };
```

Comment: Object properties are always visible. No need for getters there. what you want to probably do is using a function and expose some of the variables in the return statement.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

An accessor is not a function as a property of the object ("method"), but a function that is called when that property is [assigned (set)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/set) or [retrieved (get)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/get). Use

```
dummy.nameAccessor = 'Mazinga';
```

to invoke the setter function.

In contrast, `dummy.nameAccessor('Mazinga')` gets the property "nameAccessor" (which results in the name string) and then tries to call it as a function, which will fail. It would work if your getter returned a function, but that is not what you want here.

Answer (score 0):

`dummy.nameAccessor` is not a function, it is a string `name value is: empty`.

Answer (score -5):

Your methods syntax is not correct, try :

```
var dummy = {

    name: 'empty',
    description: 'static description',

    getName : function(){return 'name value is: ' + this.name;},
    setName : function(value){ this.name = value;},
    getDesc : function(){return 'description value is: ' + this.description;}

};
```