# How to use getter and setter methods in setting angular reactive form values for post

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I am having the below code part.

```
    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            apiCodesFile: ['']
        });
    }

    public onFileSelect(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.isFileSelected = true;
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            this.form.get('apiCodesFile').setValue(file);
        } else {
            this.isFileSelected = false;
        }
    }
```

But I need to use get/set methods to set the form value for the formControl 'apiCodesFile' rather than setting it inside 'onFileSelect' method.

I added the below code parts. But it gave an error.

```
    set apiCodesFile (val) {
        this.form.get('apiCodesFile').setValue(val);
    }

    public onFileSelect(event) {
        if (event.target.files.length > 0) {
            this.isFileSelected = true;
            const file = event.target.files[0];
            this.apiCodesFile(file);
        } else {
            this.isFileSelected = false;
        }
    }
```

Error:

```
ERROR TypeError: this.apiCodesFile is not a function
```

Please give me a solution for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessors: setter does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12194988/accessors-setter-does-not-work)

Comment: No that way did not work at all

Comment: If you use setter, you need to apply `this.apiCodesFile = "value"` to set value.

Comment: Use patchValue to set the value. Check this [Patch_Value_Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69439376/how-to-setvalue-of-a-particular-field-in-reactive-forms-when-its-an-array-of-obj/69440873#69440873)

Answer (score 2):

Please try using below code

```
apiCodesFile (val) {
   this.form.get('apiCodesFile').setValue(val);
}
```

Remove the set from apiCodesFile Function